# function works only after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

i try to add a plugin (colorpicker or datepicker) for a input field.

The form is gernerated later by an ajax call.

If i click at first time in the input fields, nothing happens.

After the second click, the function will work. What i do wrong?

Thats the part of the js-file

```
var datePickerOptions = {
format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true   
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.date-picker').datepicker(datePickerOptions);    
 });
$(document).on('click','.date-picker', function() {
   $('.date-picker').datepicker(datePickerOptions);      
});
```

and thats the part of the html file

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">'.$lang['mod1'][98].'</label>
            <div class="entry input-group">
                <input id="gebdat" class="form-control date-picker" name="1_gebdat" type="text" value="'.$_POST['1_gebdat'].'"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></button></span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Why do you turn it into a datepicker then turn it into a date picker again after you click on the datepicker?

Comment: The problem is because you need to call `datepicker()` right after you create the element in the callback of your AJAX request

Comment: and how i should do that in the best way? I though for that was the ".on" part in dthe call of the datepicker()?